# How to transform a date like "YY-MMM" to a date object using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date "22-Mar" (YY-MMM) and I want to format it in "01.03.2022" and after that transform it into a date object without using "new Date()" method.

I heard that I can do this with MomentJS but I think I write something wrong.

I tried to format this date like that but this doesn't work.

```
moment(date, 'YY-MMM').format('MM/01/YYYY').toDate()
```

My error message:

```
TypeError: moment(...).format(...).toDate is not a function
```

How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 1):

`format()` returns a string, where as the `toDate()` is only available on the MomentJS object.

So remove the `format()` if you want to convert it to a `Date`

---

If you use the 'format' to set the day to 1, you can use `date()` for that: [`.date(1)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)

---

Also, your custom format was invalid, I've changed it to `DD-MMM` to the date is proper parsed

```js
const input = '22-Mar';
const mom  = moment(input, 'DD-MMM').toDate();


console.log(mom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```